# Spark, can't get create table with partitions, but no partitions works

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, databricks

My data structure is like this

```
/mnt/path/db/table/keya=01/keyb=123
/mnt/path/db/table/keya=01/keyb=124
/mnt/path/db/table/keya=02/keyb=123
```

This creation of a table successfully works

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_table_a`(
..irrelevant schema..
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/mnt/path/db/table/keya=0101/keyb=123'
```

Then

```
select count(*) from test_table_a;
//returns
1876 
//correct
```

I can query data on that just fine, however I would like a partitioned table.

I have tried this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_table_a`(
..irrelevant schema..
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
PARTITIONED BY (
  `keya` string,
  `keyb` string)
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/mnt/path/db/table'
```

and this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_table_a`(
..irrelevant schema..
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
PARTITIONED BY (
  `keya` string,
  `keyb` string)
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/mnt/path/db/table/keya=*/keyb=*'
```

However, on both of these I get this result

```
select count(*) from test_table_a;
//returns
0 
show partitions test_table_a;
//returns
//nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating an **external partitioned table** on top of **location** (data exists in this location already), So execute the below command in your hive shell

```
hive> msck repair table <db.name>.<table_name>;
```

Check you are able to see the partition info and data in **test_table_a** table.

> **Create the table statement:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_table_a`(
..irrelevant schema..
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
PARTITIONED BY (
  `keya` string,
  `keyb` string)
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/mnt/path/db/table';
```